# Time conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert a datetime that looks like:

'Thu Jul 09 2015 08:00:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)'

to a date like 
'dd-mm-yyyy' - ie '09-07-2015'?

(preferably no special libraries used)

Comment: Is your _datetime_ a _String_ or a _Date_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider the effects of timezone. A simple implementation could be such as this

```
function myDateFormat(d) {
    var dd = d.getDate(),
        mm = d.getMonth() + 1,
        yyyy = d.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
    if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
    return dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
}

var d = new Date('Thu Jul 09 2015 08:00:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)');
myDateFormat(d); // "09-07-2015" (in client's local timezone)
```

However, note that someone in a different timezone may end up with a different date to the date in GMT+0300

If your intention is to have your timezone's date shown instead, you'll need to know your timezone's offset from *UTC* at your time (send this along with the *datetime*) you can then adjust the UTC time by this value and output what *Date* is calculating as the *UTC* time after this modification.

```
function myDateFormat(d_in, offset) {
    var d = new Date(+d_in - 60000 * offset);
        dd = d.getUTCDate(),
        mm = d.getUTCMonth() + 1,
        yyyy = d.getUTCFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
    if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
    return dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
}
```

And your offset is `-180` (*GMT+0300* is `3 * 60` minutes *ahead* `-`)

```
myDateFormat(d, -180); // "09-07-2015" (client in any timezone)
```

Comment: upvoting for specifying the client's local timezone